# What measures can be taken to prevent Server Side Request Forgery (SSRF) in a JAX-RS Application running on Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssrf

If I have a an application server that uses an implementation of JAX-RS, and is running as `*.war` file on an Apache Tomcat server, is there anything special that needs to be done or configured to prevent SSRF attacks?

My *naive* understanding is that JAX-RS application are only serving requests to certain URLs and Apache Tomcat only allows requests to certain resources.

If this is handled by default by JAX-RS or Apache Tomcat, could you explain how?

If this is not handled by default by JAX-RS nor Apache Tomcat, could you explain the best way to prevent this type of attack with these tools?

Specific versions:

- JAX-RS api 2.1
- Apache Tomcat 9.0.33

Comment: Is your JAX-RS application requesting data from other applications *based on the user input*?

Comment: @bhorkarg I have one application that sits on top of a database and one that does make a request to another application for data based on an identifier that the client system passes in. The two flows look something like this:

User -> Client System -> My Application -> (Database || Downstream Application)

Comment: If the identifier is a url or a hostname of the downstream application, then you should validate it (and keep a whitelist) to prevent SSRF.

Comment: As far as the question is concerned, there is no mention of SSRF prevention in tomcat documentation so I would assume there is no default protection. Anyways, SSRF is quite dependent on the application logic, so I would put more focus on building the protections on the app level itself.

Comment: @iraleigh did you find any fix for this?

Comment: @SundeepPidugu I haven't found anything online specifically addressing SSRF. One of the apps I work on got dinged, by our App Sec team, for not addressing it. But our App Sec Champion did not have any advice on preventing it given our tech stack. If I find anything specific, I will update the question/answer--for now I accepted the answer that mentions there is no protection by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither Tomcat nor JAX-RS documentation mentions anything to prevent SSRF attacks. So I would assume there is no protection by default.

SSRF typically abuses the trust placed in a server by other entities. Which is why in your case it is important to *vet* the vectors *used for connections initiated from the server*. So validate your input. For example, if your server depends on a user supplied URL to fetch something, then validate that URL and allow only the target hosts that you trust and block localhost.

OWASP has a [cheatsheet for SSRF](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Server_Side_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html) and gives a pretty good overview of protection methods.